# A more wide class than smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, smooth-functions

I will call a function $f$ *almost smooth* when for every point $a$ there are numbers $y_0$, $y_1$, $y_2$ ...
$$f(x) = y_0 + \frac{y_1}{1!}(x-a) + \dots + \frac{y_n}{n!}(x-a) ^n + O((x-a)^{n+1})$$
for every natural $n$.

I am unsure that an almost smooth function may be not smooth.

My question: Do these "almost smooth" functions have any use in analysis? That is, it this concept useful? Can you provide some references on the theory of almost smooth functions?

Comment: Does this hold for a single $a$ or for every $a$? If this holds just for a single $a$, then these functions need not even be continuous at any point apart from $a$ itself...

Comment: @Federico The formula must hold at every point $a$

Comment: @Federico ... or we can consider the narrower class of function where the formula holds on some interval

Comment: Hm, for almost smooth functions we can define generalized derivative (equal to $y_0$). This seems interesting

Comment: Does the constant implied by the big-Oh notation depend on $a$?

Comment: @Clayton yes, it does

Comment: @Clayton we can equivalently replace big O with small o and thus not worry on the constant

Comment: Why would a "generalized" derivative produce $y_0$ instead of $y_1$?

Comment: @Clayton Yes, should be $y_1$ instead

Comment: My proof that an almost smooth function may be not smooth was with an error

Comment: @RossMillikan No they are not. They are differentiable, but not even $C^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $y_0=f(a)$.
Secondly, almost smooth functions are differentiable. This is an immediate consequence of
$$
f(x) = f(a) + y_1 (x-a) + o(x-a) .
$$
In particular, $y_1=f'(a)$. Therefore, go and check your other [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2978532/4876) because it is incorrect. They are not much better than that. In particular, the first derivative can be discontinuous and locally unbounded.

Moreover, almost smooth functions are closed under addition and multiplication (they form a ring), but most importantly they are also closed under composition. I claim that this is a **Bad Thing™** and not a feature. The reason is basically that $(f\circ g)=(f'\circ g)g'$. When derivatives are bounded, the bounds are preserved, but when things get wild, this identity tells us that ill-behaviour gets *amplified*.

To get a taste of how horrible can these functions be, here are some examples. Notice that
$$
f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac1{|x|}\right)g(x)
$$
is almost smooth for every bounded function $g$ which is smooth in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. This is a large class of functions that can behave extremely bad near $0$, apart from decaying sufficiently fast. In particular, the first derivative can be unbounded.
We can take for instance
$$
f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac1{|x|}\right)\sin\left(\frac1{|x|}\right).
$$
[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Sin%5BExp%5B1%2FAbs%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%20Exp%5B-1%2FAbs%5Bx%5D%5D%20for%20x%20from%20-1%2F2%20to%201) you can see a plot of such $f$. Doesn't look to bad; it's still quite nice... But now we employ the composition trick to produce a monster.
I suggest you now to try to visualize $f\circ f$. Another example is $f(x+f(x))$.
[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(Sin%5BE%5E(1%2FAbs%5Bx+%2B+Sin%5BE%5E(1%2FAbs%5Bx%5D)%5D%2FE%5E(1%2FAbs%5Bx%5D)%5D)%5D%2F++++E%5E(1%2FAbs%5Bx+%2B+Sin%5BE%5E(1%2FAbs%5Bx%5D)%5D%2FE%5E(1%2FAbs%5Bx%5D)%5D))+for+x+from+.1+to+.3) is a plot. Does it look "almost smooth"?

To conclude, I don't know of any good use of this class of functions, but i think that the name *almost smooth* doesn't represent well their true nature.

Comment: My counterexample of almost smooth but not smooth function was in error. Maybe almost smooth is the same as smooth? Can you prove?

Comment: @porton No they are not the same. I provided a counterexample both in this answer and your other question.